# Angular js simple ng-include not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm new in angular js. I am trying to include simple html file in my page.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
</head>

<body ng-controller="userController">

<div class="container">
  <div ng-include src="'about.html'"></div>
</div>

<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and **about.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead><tr>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>
      Edit
    </td>
    <td>ss</td>
    <td>dd</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

But it doesn't include 'about.html' page.

What's wrong with this code?(Sorry for bad english)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you able to solve this problem? I am having the same issue.
Please post the solution if you had solved this. Below answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div ng-include="'about.html'"></div>
```

or

```
<ng-include src="'about.html'"></ng-include>
```

Comment: I tried the same example with your answer but still I am not able to include the new HTML file. I got `Page not found error`.

Comment: I just copied the sample above and put the index.html and about.html files in the same folder, and removed the ng-controller from body since I do not have a js file with a controller in it and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26335567/967638) which I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

The included file url should be relative to the client url of the including page. You are probably using some sort of web framework that abstracts your URL format.

You should put the included files together with other static files.