# Express + AngularJS + HTML: ng-include not working (404 - Page not found error)

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, express, pug

I am new to **AngularJS**. I am trying to use `ng-include` to include an external HTML page in my main HTML page. But the problem is I am not able to include it and getting 404. Following is the folder structure and the code,

**Project Folder Structure:**

[image]

**buttonClick.jade** (This is the starting page.)

```
doctype html
html(ng-app)
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        script(src='/javascripts/angular.min.js')
    body(class="mainPage")
        //include footer.html
        include pageinclude.html
```

**pageinclude.html**

```
<div>
    <div>Include Page Demo</div>
    <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

1) When I include `footer.html` page directly in the .jade file then it is working fine. But when I do the same using ng-include in the HTML file it does not work.

2) I have also tried the following ng-include ways,

```
<div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
<ng-include src="'footer.html'"></ng-include>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-include` is a client side include and as such the path to the included html file is relative to the client perception of the url.

Since jade is abstracting your folder structure and does not provide direct access to your `views` folder you should probably put the included html file on the `public` folder just as any externaly accessible file.

When you include the footer in your .jade file (As per Note 2) you are doing a server side include which uses the server directory structure.

Comment: +1 Excellent .. :) Worked like a charm when placed in the public folder.

Comment: But one question so how should I give the path to the views folder in the HTML files instead of placing the file in the public folder?

Comment: You can't. it's not publicly accessible. You can wrap an html file in another view and thus make it accessible.

Comment: Sorry I did not get this point .. `You can wrap an html file in another view and thus make it accessible`

Comment: Say you want to keep footer.html in the views folder for whatever reason. you can then create a new view that serves only footer.html. In your master html file use ng-include with the url to the new view.

Comment: Okay. I have now created a folder inside public and I am able to access these files. One last question how do I access the HTML files inside the public folder from `jade` file. I just tried and I am not able to access it.

Comment: No idea. never used jade. You can probably ask a new question to get relevant answers.

Comment: aah I got it. As Jade is directly looking for the files inside views folder. So as general rule I used `../public` to reach the files in public folder. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I also had similar problem and I'm also new in Angular and Node :)
I'm not sure that my solution is safe, so if itsn't let me know about that.

I've solved it by expose partial directory with [express.static](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in) middleware.

So add something like that to the `app.js`:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //common
app.use('/views', express.static(__dirname + '/views')); //serve views directory as assets
```

Then you can access your partial from client side:

```
<div ng-include="'/views/footer.html'"></div>
```

Comment: this seems like a bad idea since your view files (jade, ejs, whatever) can be viewed publicly